# Is there library method to convert String "1, 2, 3, 4" or "1 2 3 4" to array of integers or List<Integer>?

Tags: java

Is there any tested library method to convert String "1, 2, 3, 4" or "1 2 3 4" to array of integers or List?

I can write it myself, just library is quick and very readable.

Comment: `str.split(", ")` or `str.split(" ")` ? ([Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-))

Comment: split will not cast the elements to int, which the what the op seems to want.

Comment: Alex so you do str.split(",").forEach(string -> numberlist.add(Integer.parse(string));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in Java API method for this, but writing a helper method yourself is easy enough:

```
ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (String token : "1 2, 3 4".split("[ ,]+"))
    result.add(Integer.parseInt(token));
// result now holds { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

In Java 8 you could also take advantage of [the new Streams concept and its `map()` method](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) to shorten the code further.